# Prove that $G$ is abelian if there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$, so that $f(x)=x^m$, $f \in Aut(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with the following property: for any automorphism $f \in G$, there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x)=x^{m},\forall x\in G$.

Prove that $G$ is abelian.

Let $s,t \in G$, with $ord(s)|ord(t)$.
We know that $f:G\rightarrow G, f(x)=txt^{-1} \in Aut(G)$. Therefore $f(x)=x^m, m \in \mathbb{N}, m \geq 1.$
Then $t=t\cdot t\cdot t^{-1}=f(t)=t^m$, hence $t^{m-1}=1$, following that $ord(t)|m-1.$
Obviously, $ord(s)|m-1$, so $s^{m-1}=1$, which means $s=s^m=f(s)=tst^{-1}.$
Multiplying with $t$ on the right side, we obtain $st=ts$.

So I proved that $ts=st$, for any $s,t \in G$, with $ord(s)|ord(t)$.
But I got stuck here, because I don't know how to prove that any two elements of $G$ commute, regardless of their order.

Comment: In the original question, did you mean $f \in Aut(G)$?

Comment: Yes, $f \in Aut(G)$.

Comment: By considering just inner automorphisms, the hypothesis implies that all cyclic subgroups of $G$ are normal, and hence all subgroups of $G$ are normal. So $G$ is a so-called *Hamiltonian group*, which means that it has $Q_8$ as a direct factor. Now you just need to check that $Q_8$ has  automorphisms that do not satisfy the hypothesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime dividing $|G|$.  Let $H_p$ be the set of all elements in $G$ whose order is a power of $p$.  This is a normal subgroup; clearly it is fixed by all automorphisms, so we need to check it's a subgroup.  If $x,y\in H_p$, then we can assume $|x|$ divides $|y|$ (remember, they each have order a power of $p$). By what you've proved, they commute, and so $|xy|$  divides $|y|$; this means $xy\in H_p$, so it's a subgroup.  Note we've also proved $H_p$ is abelian.

Do this for all primes dividing $|G|$.  Clearly, $H_p\cap H_q$ is trivial when $p\neq q$. Thus they all commute, and so $\prod H_p$ is a normal abelian subgroup of $G$. We'll be done if we can show this is all of $G$.

Let $g\in G$ such that $|g|=\prod_i p_i^{\alpha_i}$. We can induct on $i$ to show that $g$ is in $\prod H_p$. The case $i=1$ is obvious.

For the inductive case, write $|g|=p^\alpha r$, where $r$ is "the rest" of the factors. Since $p^\alpha$ and $r$ are coprime, we can write $mp^\alpha+nr=1$.  Then $g^{mp^\alpha}g^{nr}=g$, and $g^{nr}$ has order a power of $p$.  Thus $g^{nr}\in H_p$, and by the induction hypothesis, $g^{mp^\alpha}\in\prod H_p$. Thus
$$ g=g^{mp^\alpha}g^{nr}\in \prod H_p$$

**EDIT**:

I should mention that once you know $G$ is abelian, it is pretty easy to prove it must be cyclic.

Comment: Every element of order a power of $p$ is in a $p$-Sylow subgroup.  Here,there is a unique $p$ Sylow subgroup since the $p$-Sylow subgroups are normal. So, all the elements of $G$ whose order is a power of $p$ is contained in this $p$-Sylow subgroup. Your subgroup $H_p$ is actually the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. So, your argument shows that every $p$-Sylow subgroup is abelian.  The group is the direct product of $p$-Sylow subgroups, so $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Yes, I tried to avoid using anything as involved as the Sylow theory, however, since it's not necessary here.

Comment: I'll post a more high-tech proof as another answer.

Comment: I think that $G $ need not be cyclic. $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb {Z}_2 $ gives a counterexample.

Comment: @S.Venkataraman: If $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb {Z}_2$ is $\langle x\rangle\times\langle y\rangle$, then the map $x\mapsto xy$, $y\mapsto y$ is an automorphism that isn't of the prescribed form. Indeed, the automorphism group in this case is $D_8$, which isn't even abelian.

Comment: We can simplify the argument in the second part as follows:  prime divisors of $\vert G\vert$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$. We need to show that $G=\prod_p H_p$.   Let $g\in G$.  Write $o(g)=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$. Let us write $n_i=\frac{o(g)}{p_i^{\alpha_i}}$.  Then, we can find $a_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a_1n_1+a_2n_2+\cdots+a_kn_k=1$.  We have $g=g^{a_1n_1}g^{a_2n_2}\cdots g^{a_kn_k}$ and each $g^{a_in_i}$ has order a power of $p_i$. So, $g^{a_in_i}$ is in $H_{p_i}$, so $g\in\prod_pH_p$.

Comment: @S.Venkataraman: That's the same proof I gave, but without the induction (relying on Bezout identity).  I'm not sure it makes sense to edit the answer, but thanks for posting the comment!

Answer (score 3):

I have made corrections in view ofthe mistake pointed out by Max and the observation of Derek Holt. Thanks Max and Derek!

Here is my modified argrument. Let $\vert G\vert=p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\ldots p_k^{n_k}$.  For each $g\in G$, there is a smallest $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $tgt^{-1}=g^x$ for all $g\in G$.  Let us denote this $x$ by $\psi(t)$.  Then, \begin{equation}g^{\psi(s)\psi(t)}=g^{\psi(st)}\forall g\in G.\ \ \ (*)
\end{equation}

From (*) we have $o(g)\mid (\psi(s)\psi(t)-\psi(st))$ for all $g\in G$ for any $s$, $t\in G$. Let
$m=lcm\{o(g)\vert g\in G\}$, i.e. the exponent of $G$. Then, it follows that $\psi(ts)\equiv \psi(t)\psi(s)\pmod{m}$. If $o(t)=k$, $1=\psi(t^k)\equiv \left(\psi(t)\right)^k\pmod{m}$, so $\psi(t)$ is coprime to $m$. Consider the map $\lambda\colon g\to\left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$ given by $t\mapsto \{\psi(t)\}$, where $\{\psi(t)\}$ is the residue class of $\psi(t)\bmod{m}$.  So, $\lambda(G)\subset \left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$.  From ( * ) we actually have group homomorphism $\lambda \colon G\to \left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{m\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$.The kernel of $\lambda$  is $Z(G)$. 
Again,  $G$ is the direct product of its $p$-Sylow subgroups since the $p$-Sylow subgroups are normal as pointed out by Derek Holt.  Let $H_p$ be the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. For any $t\in H_p$, there is an inner automorphism $t\mapsto tgt^{-1}$, so, we still have the map $\lambda$ for this case. The image of $\lambda$ restricted to $H_p$ is in $\left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^r\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$ for some $r$. The kernel of the map is $Z\left (H_p\right)$ and $H_p/Z\left(H_p\right)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^r\mathbb{Z}}\right)^*$. So, if $p$ is odd, $H_p/Z \left (H_p\right)$ is cyclic. It follows that $H_p$ is abelian.  The argument doesn't work for $2$.

Comment: Actually $|G|$ and $\phi(n)$ need not be coprime : if $p_i\mid p_j-1$ for instance.